# open system call return -1 in mojave when trying to open drive

Tags: c, objective-c, macos-mojave

When I try to open a drive sector to read using `open()`, it returns `-1` file descriptor, in MacOS Mojave.

But it works fine in other MacOS. Is there any other way to do this in mojave.

```
 cPath = "/dev/rdisk0 ";
 errno = 0;
 int fileDesc = 0;
 fileDesc = open(cPath, O_RDONLY);
 if (fileDesc == -1)
 {
   NSLog(@"%s",strerror(errno));
 }
```

Prints: "operation not permitted"

Comment: strerror shows "operation not permitted"

Comment: You should [edit] your question to add information instead of writing a comment.

Comment: Are you launching you program with `sudo` or logged as `root`?

Comment: Yes my main app launches as root.

Comment: Just a guess: As an avenue to explore try looking into *System Integrity Protection* (SIP). HTH

Comment: SIP is enable..It is working fine in MacOS older then mojave even if SIP is enabled but not in mojave.